# Not able to configure sentry 10.0.0 even i have changed the image tag in values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, sentry

```
helm install stable/sentry \
  --version 4.3.0 \
  --set images.sentry.tag=10.0.0
```

Not able to configure Sentry 10.0.0. Could you please help me with required changes and let me know why it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `--set` should only contain `image.tag` as one can see from [their `values.yaml` file](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/sentry/values.yaml#L6), additionally confirmed by looking at their [`web-deployment.yaml`](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/sentry/templates/web-deployment.yaml#L57) which uses the same values expression